# Ker and Im of Linear Transformation with given vectors

Tags: linear-transformations

For given linear transformation $:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$$(0,1,-1,1)=(1,2,1),\quad (1,-1,0,-1)=(1,-1,1),\quad (1,0,-1,0)=(2,1,2)$$

Find all the possibilities for $\dim Ker(T)$ and $\dim Im(T)$

Tried to do matrix for the vectors of the origin but didn't understand why. Any help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Gilad It's not clear what you mean when you say that you tried to "do matrix for the given vectors"

Comment: I did matrix with the of the vectors and find that one is linear independent, thought its meant that kerT>1 and imT>2 but didn't know why

Comment: What can you say about the rank of the two family vector from $R^4$ and $R^3$ ?